# Silent Uninstallation

Tags: android

I am working for manufacture of cell phones. we develop for the Android platform, therefore we can sign our applications and have system permissions, for example we can use

the packagemanager.installPackage(|..) method, which gives us the ability to install APK's without the user involvement.

I would like to know, if any one you know about an Un-instantiation method which would uninstall apk's silently without user-involvement?

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is functionality in there some where to do this - [Google uses remote kill switch to uninstall Android apps](http://androinica.com/2010/06/24/google-uses-remote-kill-switch-to-uninstall-android-apps/), but I haven't seen any details on where you would find this. But as a user I would be very unhappy with a handset which silently removed apps without telling me - even if the app was a security threat, if I had installed it, I would want to be told it was being removed.

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at it, and you right, I also didn't find any API with the requested methods.